# RegExp to match any string except two reserved strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

Probably a simple one but my knowledge of creating regular expressions is a little vague.

I'm trying to match any string followed by a comma and a space except if it is 'Bair Hugger' or 'Fluid Warmer'

Here is what I have so far

```
var re_comma = new RegExp("\w+[^Bair Hugger|Fluid Warmer]" + ", ", "i");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean to the end of a sentence or the whole string after the `,`?

Comment: @Termi The string and the comma and space following it. but nothing after that. Hope thats clearer

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Good question :) Some kind of warming device used in theatres

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**New answer**

Regarding your example I'd say it is really easier to split the string and iterate over it:

```
function filter(str, delim, test) {
    var parts = str.split(delim),
        result = [];

    for(var i = 0, len = parts.length; i < len; i++) {
        if(test(parts[i])) result.push(parts[i]);
    }

    return result.join(delim);
}

str = filter(str, ', ', function(s) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    return s === 'bair hugger' || s === 'fluid warmer';
});
```

Otherwise, your expression becomes something like this:

```
new RegExp("(^|, )(?!(?:Bair Hugger|Fluid Warmer)(?:$|, )).+?(, |$)", "i");
```

and you have to use a callback for the replacement to decide whether to remove the preceding `,` or trailing `,` or not:

```
str = str.replace(re_comma, function(str, pre, tail) {
    return pre && tail ? tail : '';// middle of the string, leave one
});
```

The intention of this code is less clear. Maybe there is a simpler expression, but I think filtering the array is still cleaner.

---

**Old answer:** (doesn't solve the problem at hand but provides information regarding regular expressions).

`[]` denotes a *character class* and will only match **one** character out of the ones you provided. `[^Bair Hugger|Fluid Warmer]` is the same as `[^Bair Huge|FldWm]`.

You could use a negative lookahead:

```
new RegExp("^(?!(Bair Hugger|Fluid Warmer), ).+?, $", "i");
```

Note that you have to use `\\` inside a string to produce one `\`. Otherwise, `"\w"` becomes `w` and is not a special character sequence anymore.You also have to anchor the expression.

**Update:** As you mentioned you want to match any string before the comma, I decided to use `.` instead of `\w`, to match any character.

Comment: Do you mean `(?!` instead of `(?!=`?

Comment: This also excludes strings that just start with one of the "forbidden words" (like `Bair Hugger Refill, `).

Comment: @Felix The hidden field will look something like this "Blanket, Fluid Warmer, Bair Hugger" So i'm trying to remove the word "Blanket" and the ", " following it to leave just "Fluid Warmer, Bair Hugger". Thanks

Comment: @Mark: Mmh.... it's possible but the expression is getting more complex. I'd say it's easier to just split the string and compare each entry.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks, I think you might be right, I'm going to give that a go.

Comment: @Mark: I added an example for the expression. There might be a simpler one, I don't know. But still, it is more difficult to understand (and more importantly: to extend) than splitting the string and filtering the resulting array.

Comment: @Felix: Thanks for the solution and the explanations on regular expressions. You were right, a lot easier to split and then interrogate the array.

Answer (score 0):

I love regex and Felix Kling answer is correct :)

However for such simple matching I would normally use something like below

```
function contains(str, text) {
   return str.indexOf(text) >= 0;
}

if(contains(myString, 'random')) {
   //myString contains "random"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and useful for the future but i can't use it for what i'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
    reg =/(?:Bair Hugger|Fluid Warmer),| (.*)/
    str='Bair Hugger, lalala'
    reg.exec(str)
    >> ["Bair Hugger, lalala", " lalala"]
    newStr = reg.exec(str)[1]
```

Comment: How would you use this to remove `Blanket, ` from `"Blanket, Fluid Warmer, Bair Hugger"` ?